# Best way to create CI/CD pipeline for GCP BigQuery using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, google-bigquery, continuous-integration

I am looking for the best way to create CI/CD pipeline for GCP BigQuery using Azure DevOps.
I need repositories in Azure Devops, and automatically have CI and CD to our Dev/QA and PROD environments in GCP. Also, how to set up automatic builds in Azure DevOps for GCP master branch code? Is there a way to integrate BigQuery and Azure Devops repositories ?
We have to use Azure DevOps for Project, repository and pipeline management. So trying ways to build and deploy to GCP Bigquery from Azure Devops. Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all congratulations on your first post.

Yes definitely you can integrate Azure Devops with BigQuery.
A good read [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/creating-cicd-pipeline-vsts-kubernetes-engine).

But from your question, I failed to understand what you are trying to deploy. Is it some client code which will connect to BQ to run query and fetch data or is it a Dataflow job starting from ingesting data?

There are different ways to do each of them.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to deploy just the Bigquery coomponents, such as tables. views, etc. Lets say in the future I have a table change( say addition of fields) , then I can use DevOps pipeline to build and deploy just my Bigquery component. Looks like I can use gcloud scripts to deploy code to bigquery, the only thing I am trying to figure out is to how to merge code into Azure Devops repository to automatically trigger the build.

Comment: Yes indeed you can use gcloud bq scripts or yaml files to deploy views, tables. you have to maintain versions of these scripts/yaml in repository.